# login with rsh having zero size terminal (stty)

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, stty, rsh

I've received a very peculiar problem all of sudden to the Linux hosts while doing rsh to them from a remote site and them opening a file it returns the file opened very limited on the terminal saying that the `stty size` shows `0 0`.

Secondly, this is not limited to a particular hosts its for all the users whosoever doing rsh to the remote machine over the WAN.

Another weird scene is that , if we do rsh from some near WAN location the it works fine while others not.

```
$ stty size
0 0
```

### Client connections & OS:

Both Source and Destination are using same OS.

Below is Just an example while opening a file it only opens up to half window.

[image]

I'm just suspecting if a N/W change like at the switch/routing level for network may impact this.

### Linux releases :

RedHat: all versions

CentOS: all versions

Comment: People are _bound_ to chip in with _Why on Earth are you using RSH?  Over a WAN, at that‽_.  Setting that aside, observe that there are at least two RSH server implementations on Debian Linux alone (netkit-rsh and rsh-redone).  This question really should, for the benefit of answerers who aren't just going to dismiss out of hand such an easily interceptable protocol for providing too broad a range of possibilities, state the exact client and server softwares being used.

Comment: @JdeBP, You can't fight with the entire world on the earth :) saying that , i understand that being a sysadmin and already advocated about the drawbacks and flows of the rsh but users to whom i'm supporting are "bound to chip" to use to do that since long and i'm just starting my stint here. But the problem is that why they are facing it all of sudden, appreciate your comments.

Comment: [Actually, you can.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14699081)  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP,  thanks for the link it states the very Valid point which i know as in my prior  stint we forcibly closed the rsh/rlogin for use but somehow in my new stint its like a DNA for them and i need to figure out before i can more strongly advocate about its provocation and bad practices.

Comment: To debug this, you can sniff the net looking for \377 \377 's' 's' followed by 4 2-byte integers in the octet stream shortly after connection. It's possible the block of octets is getting broken up into multiple packets and the server doesn't read all 12 at once. You can also ask the user to resize their window and see if this results in that sequence being received on the server. If it's being received but `stty size` doesn't change, then you might strace rlogind and see if it's ever invoking the TIOCSWINSZ ioctl.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, placing stty/resize into the user .cshrc file works as a workaround.